# React-router doesn't sync history and Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to get react-router and redux to work together.
When my component mounts, I make an ajax-call and until this one finishes I want to show a loading-message. Once the ajax-call returns successfully, I reroute to the correct page.
However, whenever I change routes programmatically, react-router doesn't update the shown page.  Also, I don't want to use the browser's history but an internal one (memory history) and can't find any examples of this working together with redux.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, createMemoryHistory, useRouterHistory, routerReducer } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

let appHistory;

export default class Transfer extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        myAjaxCall(function(){
            // Reroute
            appHistory.push('/projectrepresentation'); // changes a route change in the router, but doesn't display /projectrepresentation
        })
    }

    constructor(){
        const reducers = combineReducers({
          routing: routerReducer
        })

        store = createStore(reducers);

        // Create an enhanced internal (!) history that syncs navigation events with the store
        let createAppHistory = useRouterHistory(createMemoryHistory);
        appHistory = createMemoryHistory();
        history = syncHistoryWithStore(appHistory, store);
    }

    render () {

        return <Provider store={store}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    <Route path="/" component={() => <div>Loading</div>}>
                        <Route path="projectrepresentation" component={() => <div>Project Representation</div>}/>
                        <Route path="export" component={() => <div>Export</div>}/>
                    </Route>
                </Router>
              </Provider>
    }

}
```

Comment: I am confused by this example. You should not be creating `store`, calling `combineReducers`, or `syncHistoryWithStore` inside the `render()` method. The `render()` method can be called thousands of times during the lifecycle of your app! You are effectively resetting the store state on every render. Instead, move that code to the top of the file so it only executes once.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I adapted the example and unfortunately, it's not working yet. The route-change after the ajax-call is being picked up by history, but the route that react-router renders is still "/" instead of "/projectrepresentation"

Comment: I found the problem: The loading component at "/" didn't render any children.